# How to change UK date format in LogicApp

Tags: datetime, azure-logic-apps, date-conversion, formatdatetime

Im trying to convert a U.K. input date (dd-MM-yyyy) to format (yyyy-MM-dd)

I tried

```
"@formatDateTime('15-03-2019','yyyy-MM-dd')" ==> Error
```

but got error:

```
'In function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided 
for date time string '15-03-2019' was not valid. The datetime 
string must match ISO 8601 format.'
```

How do I go about converting this input date? The input format is (dd-MM-yyyy) and cannot be changed.

I can easily convert from (MM-dd-yyyy) as shown below, but im not able to convert from (dd-MM-yyyy)

```
"@formatDateTime('03-15-2019','yyyy-MM-dd')" ==> OK
```

Comment: The timestamp does not seem to recognize `dd-MM-yyyy`, have you tried using split to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date and time functions` provided by `azure logic app` cannot recognize the timestamp in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

After my research, there is no existing function that can directly solve this problem, but you can use [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#substring) and [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#concat) to deal with this problem.

The workflow of the logic app looks like this:

[image]

The expression of the `formatDataTime`:

```
formatDateTime(concat(substring(<your-date-string>,6,4),'-',substring(<your-date-string>,3,2),'-',substring(<your-date-string>,0,2)),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```